# Deserialization issue of Java object received within XML message

Tags: java, xml, deserialization

I receive an XML message (over an HttpURLConnection) that contains a serialized Java object. This is the received XML message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><Olive><Responses><Character>aced0005737200116f626a656374732e43686172616374657200000000000000000200034c00056974656d737400154c6a6176612f7574696c2f41727261794c6973743b4c00086c6f636174696f6e7400124c6a6176612f6c616e672f537472696e673b4c00046e616d6571007e00027870737200136a6176612e7574696c2e41727261794c6973747881d21d99c7619d03000149000473697a657870000000037704000000037400084954454d312d49447400084954454d322d49447400084954454d332d4944787400035858587400044a6f686e</Character></Responses></Olive>
```

What I want to do is to deserialize the Java object which is contained within the `<Character>` element. (The first four characters "aced" reveals that we are dealing with serialized content. So far so good.)

I'm using this code to grab the characters within `<Character>` and deserialize them into a Java object:

```
Node characterElement = responsesElementChildren.item(0);  // <Character>
String characterSerialized = characterElement.getTextContent();
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( characterSerialized.getBytes() );
ObjectInputStream ins = new ObjectInputStream( bais );
objects.Character retrievedCharacter = (objects.Character) ins.readObject();
```

However, the above operation fails and I get this exception:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 61636564
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at network.requests.RequestRetrieveCharacter.addResponse(RequestRetrieveCharacter.java:99)
    at network.GameServer.ask(GameServer.java:151)
    at Client.main(Client.java:43)
```

I cannot tell if the received serialized data is okay or not, so I really don't know if the problem is here in the deserialization or actually in the serialization (on the sending side where the Java object is serialized and packed into an XML message).

Any hints are very welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: The input stream is corrupted, that's why! Check why it is getting corrupted.

Comment: @Octopus This may very well be true, but how can I tell? Invalid stream header of 61636564 seems okay to me, since that corresponds to "aced" in ASCII, which in turn means STREAM_MAGIC (according to this page: http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-serialization/).

Comment: Found an answer elsewhere. I'll put it here for future reference. The problem was in getBytes, since it reads each character separately and assigns it to one byte. Instead, one character (hex value of 0-A) should go into 4 bits (a half byte). Ended up using this solution: `ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary( characterSerialized ) );`

Answer (score 1):

The magic number at the head of serialized java blobs isn't the ascii string "ACED", it's 0xACED, followed by a version halfword (here: 0x0005). What you're seeing in that xml looks like it should be interpreted as a hex representation and not an ascii string.